# Conversão de valores booleanos para números

Tags: python

Como faço para que a resposta de `False` seja `0` e `True` seja `1`

igual em C?

Ou seja, desejo que a resposta de:
`u=(1>2)`

seja `0` e não `False`?

Obrigado

Comment: O que quer dizer com resposta ? Escrever na consola ? Porquê a tag `c` ? Está a tentar escrever `0` quando é `False` e `1` quando é `True` ?

Answer (score 4):

Basta fazer o cast para `int`

```
u=(1>2)
print(int(u))
```